# How can I fill an array with input from the user?

Tags: java, arrays, input

I need to fill array `q` with input from the user using the `InputDialog` and then use it later for calculating the total ( total += (priceOfProduct * quantity) , however I am not sure how to go about doing this. I have tried something like `q(nextInt());`.

```
private String [] product = {"Shirts", "Jeans", "Hats", "Pants", "Shoes"};
private int [] q = new int[5];

public void inputOrder()
{
    //ask user how many of each item they wish to buy.
    for (int count = 0; count < product.length; count++)
    {

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many " + product[count] + "would     you like to purchase?");

    //read input from user
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?  What you've posted here isn't remotely legal or complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Integer.parseInt` or `scanner.nextInt` and then store it in the array like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Foo {
    static String [] product = {"Shirts", "Jeans", "Hats", "Pants", "Shoes"};
    static int [] q = new int[5];
    static int total;
    private static int quantity = 1; // Either input this value from the user or initialized it with your own value

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for (int count = 0; count < product.length; count++) {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many " + product[count] + "would     you like to purchase?");
            q[count] = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(q));

        System.out.println(calcTotal());
    }

    public static double calcTotal() { for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) { total += (getPrice(i) * quantity); } return total; }

    private static int getPrice(int i) {
        return q[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! now how would I use that in this method?
    public double calcTotal()
 {

  for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++)
  {
   total += (getPrice(i) * quantity);
  }
  return total;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can add following to the code you provided :

```
q[count] = s.nextInt();
```

But this method is not preferrable. You must use regular expression to accomplish it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a price for each product. 
This should work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inputOrder();
    }

    public static void inputOrder() {
        String[] product = {"Shirts", "Jeans", "Hats", "Pants", "Shoes"};
        int[] q = new int[5];

        float total = 0.f;

        //ask user how many of each item they wish to buy.
        for (int count = 0; count < product.length; count++) {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many " + product[count] + " would you like to purchase?");

            // Prices
            float priceOfProduct = 0.f;
            if(product[count].equals("Shirts")) {
                priceOfProduct = 100.1f;
            }
            if(product[count].equals("Jeans")) {
                priceOfProduct = 100.1f;
            }
            if(product[count].equals("Hats")) {
                priceOfProduct = 100.1f;
            }
            if(product[count].equals("Pants")) {
                priceOfProduct = 100.1f;
            }
            if(product[count].equals("Shoes")) {
                priceOfProduct = 100.1f;
            }

            // Total
            total += priceOfProduct * Integer.parseInt(input);

        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "TOTAL = " +total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnyClass{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] a){
        System.out.println("How many numbers you want to enter: "); 
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Now enter "+n+" numbers: ");
        for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();              
    }
  }
```